# How do I display custom fields in the posts using types plug-in in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am presently using types plug-in to display the event list, I am able to add the custom fields for admin to enter date and location, but I am unable to display the custom fields along with the posts in the site, please tell me the solution.

I tried with the following code, but no use,

```
$key="wpcf-date"; echo get_post_meta(4, $key, true);


$querystr = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta";

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

echo $pageposts;
```

Comment: Are you using Advanced Custom Fields plugin ?

Comment: I am using types plugin

Answer (score 0):

Within the [Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), just do :

```
$wpcfdate = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'wpcf-date', true );
echo $wpcfdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

On the page where you are doing the code did you defined wpdb as below..

> global $wpdb;

Try to echo the ID above the 2 lines given by RafH so that you will know whether ID is coming or not.

> echo get_the_ID();